'fatal error: Unable to locate credentials' in Docker build after EC2 upgrade to IMDSv2
I have recently upgraded a GHA runner EC2 instance to use IMDSv2, after the upgrade my build pipeline is failing with error - "fatal error: Unable to locate credentials" at Docker build step while executing 'aws s3 cp <> <>' from Docker file. If I switch the GHA runner instance to use IMDSv1 the Docker build goes successfully.
I found out from aws docs that AWS CLI – 1.16.289 is the minimum version that supports IMDSv2. From my Docker file 'awscli noarch 1.18.147-1.amzn2.0.2' is getting installed using 'yum install awscli -y' command but still it looks like that the aws cli-1.18 is working with IMDSv1 only.
What is it that I am missing here? Can aws cli be forced/configured to use IMDSv2 only? Thanks in advance.

Looks like it is installing AWS CLI v1. Can you just try to install the latest AWS CLI v2 and see if the issue persists? The cmd to use in your docker file is : RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" && 
unzip awscliv2.zip && 
./aws/install
